# What are those image tags that appear in Facebook comments and Flickr photo descriptions?

Tags: facebook, flickr, images

I have seen some strange text in some Facebook comments

```
Some random comment made by a user followed by some machine generated tag

[cid:image001.png@01CC0B1B.C4242F30]
```

While searching for such pattern in Google, I found that some Flickr photos are also titled in the same pattern.

I think this format is inserted when you reply the FB comments by e-mail and there is an image as signature, but I don't even know if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to comment using e-mail. When someone has an image signature, the e-mail client can insert this code to refer the image.

Comment: See RFC 2392 for the full documentation of the cid url scheme.  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2392